# How to change the text of labelFor in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Controller

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Signup")]
 public ActionResult Signup_post(UserEditModel model)
 {             
     if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();

     _registrationServices.Saveuser(model);
     model.IsSubmitted = true;
     model.Message = "Successfully Registered";
     return View(model);
}
```

View

```
if (Model != null)
{
    if (Model.IsSubmitted != null && Model.IsSubmitted.Value)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, "Idon'twantthistext", new { @class = "alert-success" })
    }
}
```

I'm changing my model Message to successfully registered in controller but on the view it is still rendering "Idon'twantthistext", also if I send blank or nothing in labelfor text then it shows "Message " as Text. I just want that label should show the text which i'm sending from model.
I Hope i'm clear.

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor()` is used for rendering the name of the property, not its value. If you want the value of the property, then use `@Html.TextBoxFor()`

Comment: Thanks bro...I was confused with that I did =
  @Html.Label(Model.Message, new { @class = "text-success" })
Now its working

Comment: What would be the point of that? You generating a label which is a html element associated with a control (so when you click on it it set the focus to the associated control) but you don't have an associated control. Use a `<div>` or `<span>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//LabelFor is used to generate the label of Field like Message, User, Password etc
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message) 

//Label is used to generate the label for Value of Field (Just for view) like "Hello!", "Admin", "M4rt!4n" etc
@Html.Label("Message", Model.Message)

//TextBoxFor is used to generate the Edit for Value of field (To be edited) like "Hello!", "Admin", "M4rt!4n" etc
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Message)
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Html.LabelFor is just used for displaying name of properties not for text.**

All i did 
@Html.Label(Model.Message, new { @class = "text-success" }) 
Now it's working.
Thanks to **@Stephen Muecke** for sharing this knowledge